# How to pass a mvc-mini-profiler connection to a base class from MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler, dapper

Given this snippet of code

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    private static SqlConnection _sqlConnection;

    protected SqlConnection GetOpenConnection()
    {
        if (_sqlConnection == null)
        {
            _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        }
        return _sqlConnection;
    }

    protected abstract void Execute();
}

public class FooImpl : Foo
{

    protected override void Execute()
    {
        var myConn = GetOpenConnection();
        var dog = myConn.Query<dynamic>("select 'dog' Animal");
        var first = dog.First();

        string animalType = first.Animal;
        // more stuff here
    }
}
```

How would you wrap the connection in a profiled connection if you don't have access to the connection creation process? Rewrite the code in the super class and wrap it there? This would involve changing hundreds of classes that inherit from the base. I'd prefer a way to change the base class, with as little changes necessary to the supers.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after a bit of trial and error I compromised and added a ref to MvcMiniProfiler in the base library and changed the connection code a bit.

```
    protected DbConnection GetOpenConnection()
    {
        if (_connection == null)
        {
            _connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection string "].ConnectionString);
            _connection.Open();
        }
        return MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(_connection, MiniProfiler.Current); 
    }

    private static SqlConnection _connection;
```

This works for both hosting in the MVC project (for profiling purposes, where we don't have that capability (QA/Prod Databases)) and WPF/Windows Service

Comment: Nice; while it is a *little* annoying having to hack around the connection creation, the results are usually enlightening enough to take the sour taste away ;p

Comment: Totally, I just showed this off to our devs and the light-bulbs started flashing.

Comment: It gets better. I showed our DBA the queries I thought were under performing, they were coming in at around 150ms and the first thing he said was, "You know if you changed that parameter from nvchar(4000) to  varchar(15) to might get better performance" yeah, we did ALL queries come in at under 10ms now. Holy Crap! Per the spec http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ Ansi Strings and varchar

Comment: awesome! really pleased with that result